# How to open/pop-up a text file from C++ code

Tags: c++, file

I am making an exercise-logger program in C++. I have written the code for the login process, I just can't seem to figure out how to pop up their(that specific user's) log file. I want the program to open up the text file (in notepad) when the user has logged in. So that the user may see their previous workout logs. Is there a function in the standard file handling provided by C++?

Comment: A simple way in Windows (assuming that's the OS) is to use [ShellExecute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecutea) .  Provided you're opening a file with an extension that is registered with some application, then `ShellExecuteA(NULL, "open", path_to_file, NULL, NULL, SW_SHOW);` will do it -- using Windows to determine what application to open the file in.